# Can't find wifi on VM Ubuntu 14

Tags: wireless

I am using ubuntu on Vmplayer VM, thing is, cable ethernet is working no problem, but when I want to use wifi, i cannot find it in connections.

```
$ sudo modprobe -r iwlwfi
modprobe: FATAL: module iwlwfi not found
```

Output of: lspci -nn |grep -i net   is

```
02:01.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 79c970 [PCnet32 LANCE] [1022:2000] (rev 10)
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Normally a virtual guest system does not get access to the host's network devices, but instead the VM software emulates a virtual wired network card for the guest system, which is then connected to the internet e.g. through a NAT or bridge or whatever you set up on the virtualizer. If you need to use the host's wifi from the VM, you'll have to set up PCI-passthrough or something similar to grant the VM direct access to the hardware.

Comment: And how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The VM does not have a WiFi device. How did you configure the VM? To pass the wired NIC through to be managed by the guest OS rather than the host? You would need to do the same for your WiFi device, if you want to manage it in the guest, but then it would not be usable from the host.

The easiest thing to do is to simply have your VM configured to bridge the network from the host, and it will appear as "wired" in the guest, but it will just be a bridge to whatever you are using in your host. Then, you manage the actual network connection from the host OS.

Comment: I haven't configured anything. Can you help me with this? How should I configure it so it shall bridge the network from the host?

Comment: It is the default configuration, AFAIK. If you didn't change that, then it should just work. If you did change it, then you can go in the settings for the VM, and change the network config.

Comment: I went to network adapter config in VMware and saw that it is already enabled, as you say. It is already set to bridged. But, when I play the machine, in connections, it sais that it is connected to wired network (wifi in reality), but when i try to load any page it just doesn't work. What bugs me is that everything is fine when I use ethernet cable but with wifi it does not work.

Comment: Well, I don't know what to tell you about that. If that is your actual question then I suggest you edit your question and rewrite it to describe your actual problem and ask a question about that. It seems you have some other problem, which is not quite what you asked about here.

Comment: I somehow got around this by myself. But thank you nevertheless. Problem was, bridged connection was not working, all I did is set up to NAT and it worked no problem.